# Core-Data: Fetch objects from 3 entities into one fetch and sort by date?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I could use some help breaking down this puzzle.

1) I want to fetch objects from 3 entities ('A','B','C') in Core-Data (they all have different data types, except 'date') - have them in one big fetch, somehow? Should they have relations to a new entity 'D' or?

2) Later, I want to sort the big fetch by date (but I dont think it's an issue for me if I have the whole fetch).

So if any can help me pointing out 1), I would really appreciate it.

Comment: "Best Practice" can be seen as an invitation to opinionated discussion, so I took the liberty to remove that phrasing from the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple approach, easy to verify and - if needed - debug:

1. Do 3 distinct fetches, one from each entity.
2. Add the results to an array.
3. Sort the array by date.

Comment: Ok I actually thought there was some magic in core-data. I will leave the question open a little while.

Comment: Infact - it sounds expensive doing this each time. Is there a cache/design approach you could recommand?

Comment: @NerujaJoseph Core Data is quite efficient, so I wouldn't worry about optimising it before I have some measurements with real-life data.